# Updating the 'version' field within package.json

Tags: npm

The `package.json` file usually starts with `name`, `version`, `scripts`, `dependencies`. My questions is should I update the `version` manually , say, every time I make a release on GitHub?

While doing `npm init`, the `version` within `package.json` is defaulted to `0.0.0`. As my app grows, should I update it evey now and then viz. `1.0.0`, `2.0.1` etc.

**NOTE:** This is not regarding the *version* of different packages/dependencies but for the app itself.

Answer (score 16):

The package version is mostly relevant when you actually publish your module on a public (or private) repository. You might also want to use it for yourself or within your company to communicate code changes in a standard way, called semantic versioning: https://semver.org/. But that's up to you.

There is even a command for that: `npm version`

```
# From 1.0.0 -> 1.0.1
npm version patch 

# From 1.0.1 -> 1.1.0
npm version minor

# From 1.1.0 -> 2.0.0
npm version major
```

Details: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version